# Why does it complain Missing separate debuginfos about my c++ with gdb?

Tags: c++, gdb

My OS: `CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)`

I am debugging a c++ program with:

```
gdb demo_test
```

But I got an error:

```
Breakpoint 1, Log (level=2, msg=0x7ffff79df035 "[%s]:default model:%s") at ./api/test/test.cpp:16
16      va_start(ap, msg);
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-324.el7_9.x86_64 libgcc-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64 libstdc++-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64
```

Then I did:

```
yum install yum-utils
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos
Package yum-utils-1.1.31-54.el7_8.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Then I did:

```
# debuginfo-install glibc
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id
Could not find debuginfo for main pkg: glibc-2.17-324.el7_9.x86_64
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package nss-softokn-freebl-3.53.1-6.el7_9.x86_64
No debuginfo packages available to install
```

This doesn't fix the issue. I also tried to remove the -02 flag from the g++:

```
g++ -g -Wall  -O2  ./api/test/test.cpp  ./${NAME}.so -o demo_test $(CINCLUDE)  $(CLIB)
```

But it doesn't help either. How can I possibly fix the issue? Really thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless you want to debug the standard libraries, you don't need debug-info for them.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I don't need to debug standard libraries, but it doesn't stop at my breakpoints. How to deal with that? I tried set break points at different places.

Comment: OK. @Someprogrammerdude, you are right. I can debug with the warning info.

Comment: If you have problems with breakpoints then that's a completely different problem, and it warrants a completely different question.